# Laravel Inheritance - Auto instantiate by database field

Tags: php, database, oop, laravel, amazon-s3

I have the following classes:

```
abstract class File extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'files';
}

class LocalFile extends File {
}

class RemoteFile extends File {
}
```

I only have `files` table, `LocalFile` or `RemoteFile` table doesn't exists. `files` table has a `type` field with has the either `App\LocalFile` or `App\RemoteFile` stored.

Is there a way to **auto** cast the file's subclass during a `find`?

**Note:**
I have other models implemented with *morph*, but I can't see use of morph here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after global scopes. These allow you to apply a scope to a model for every query that is done using the model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#global-scopes

You could apply a global scope to both of your models so that `RemoteFile` only looks at `type === 'App\RemoteFile'` and vice-versa for the `LocalFile` model

Comment: Global Scope is a 5.2 exclusive feature? I can't find the 5.1.x doc of this feature :(

Comment: Nerver mind, just found it haha, I will test this out.

Comment: They're all the way back in 4 too :)